# Spring Cloud Config Server: Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, spring-cloud-config

As far as I understood it is not possible to setup Spring Cloud Config server with Mercurial.
Maybe somebody encountered a similar request and knows of a workaround or a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: I know what Spring Cloud and Mercurial are, but I don't understand what you're trying to do.  Project configuration would certainly belong in your source code management system.  You build, package, and deploy from SCM.  What is missing?

Comment: I want to setup Dynamic Configuration Server via Spring Cloud. In the examples I've seen, this is done via getting properties or yml files from GIT. And the setup url pattern in Spring Cloud is: `spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri...` I'm assuming I can't commit and push my .properties (or yml) files to mercurial and have Spring Clould Config server get them from there.

Comment: I use Jenkins for CI.  Once it creates the package, it is deployed to the cloud.  Cloud never reaches back into SCM system.

Comment: @duffymo I am using Jenkins also for deploying my microservices. I need to have a config server that can be used by different microservices. I don't want to have my configuration files inside my services and I want to keep track of what is being changed there separately.

Comment: Someone else will have to help you besides me.

Comment: @duffymo no problem. This is achieved by using GIT with Spring Cloud. Now I want to understand if it is possible also with Spring Cloud + Mercurial.

Comment: Sounds like it should just work with different URL and command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is pretty simple. In your `application.properties` of the Spring Cloud Config Server application define:

```
# tells spring to run without git
spring.profiles.active=native
# where the .properties or .yml files will be located
spring.cloud.config.server.native.search-locations=file:///{user.home}/config-repo
```

Source: https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html -> File system backend.